# Using loop variable from ".." loop causes type conversion?

Tags: rust

I have a really simple timing loop that users `..` up to a maximum.  However, when I **use** the loop variable inside the block (here as an index) it appears to cause the variable type to change.  If I *do not* touch the loop variable then the stopwatch has no issue.

```
let sw = Stopwatch::start_new();
let all_data = vec!["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
let iters = 2;
for x in 0..iters {
    println!("Message: {:?}", all_data[x]);
}
println!("Thing took {}ms per", sw.elapsed_ms() / iters);
```

This give me a type error when printing out the elapsed time.  It appears to have changed to a `usize`?

I can fix this by using `all_data[x as usize]` though.  Is Rust actually changing the actual variable somehow, or is the type inference just taking the very last usage and assuming that type?

```
src/main.rs:95:55: 95:58 error: mismatched types [E0308]
src/main.rs:95     println!("Thing took {}ms per", sw.elapsed_ms() / iters);
                                                                     ^~~
<std macros>:2:27: 2:58 note: in this expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
src/main.rs:95:5: 95:60 note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
src/main.rs:95:55: 95:58 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:95:55: 95:58 note: expected type `i64`
src/main.rs:95:55: 95:58 note:    found type `usize`
src/main.rs:95:37: 95:58 error: the trait bound `i64: std::ops::Div<usize>` is not satisfied [E0277]
src/main.rs:95     println!("Thing took {}ms per", sw.elapsed_ms() / iters);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What type is `x`?

```
let iters = 2;
```

Well, the `let` doesn't *specify* a type, and a bare `2` could be *any* kind of integer, so... *I dunno.*

```
0..iters
```

Well, a bare `0` could be *any* kind of integer, so... *I dunno.*

```
all_data[x]
```

*A-ha!*  There's only *one* implementation of `Index` usable on a `Vec`, and it's `Index<usize>`, which means `x` **must** be a `usize`, which means `0..iters` **must** be a `Range<usize>`, which means `iters` **must** be a `usize`!

---

(But if you don't use it...)

Well, I never got any indication as to what the type of `x` was, and it must *have* a type, so... `i32`?  **shrug**

---

Integer types default to `i32` in the absence of more conclusive inference information.  By using it to index a `Vec`, you told Rust that it's supposed to be a `usize`.

Comment: The story sounds a little mean spirited, until you read it as the rust compiler thinking!  I **assumed** that the type would be inferred from first assignment, _not_ from later use of a derived variable.  First assignment is a i32.  Then the use of a loop variable changes that _outside_ variable type to a compatible one. That seems really odd to me, very confusing at least, but as always there is probably a "very good reason" (tm).   Ok... off to figure out lifetimes!

Comment: To clarify, everywhere i've worked something like "var x = 3;" would make X the integer type, same as a textual substitution to "int x = 3;".  The inferrence is a convenience.  I guess that rustc is doing a lot more work and this method enables other more complcated use cases (hence the `very good reason`).  I tend to reason about lines in isolation ("what is this statement doing", "what did that expression evaluate to") and I think thats the source of confusion.  I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around why this is good, but just knowing is 1/2 the battle.

Comment: @AndrewBacker In Rust, type information can flow "backwards" through the code.  To put it another way: the type of something can be inferred based on how it's *used*.  This is why Rust can have return type deduction, where something like C++ can't.

Comment: Ok, that is cool.  And it explains some other very strange looking behavior I am having why trying to copy a function out of one context and into another.  It knows what the return type of the function is, so its inferring the type parameters of the final expression... wow.  And ouch.  Lots to think about now.

Comment: @AndrewBacker if you want to learn more about type deducing system (Rust uses the same as, e.g. Haskell) there is good article on Wikipedia: [Hindley–Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system)